# HTML CSS Layout with bg image in lower div

Tags: html, css, layout, footer

How can I have div 'lower' fill the lower part of the screen with it's bg image?

Div 'upper' grows depending on the content.

The red line marks the viewport.

Here I have an example how I did it with a table : [Splendid](http://www.splendidmusic.nl/)

But I want it tableless!!

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like at this point?

Comment: just div upper & div lower in a wrapper div...

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you don't want there to be a scrollbar in the image above?

Comment: ... and that if there was enough content in the upper div, you wouldn't see the bottom one at all?

Comment: Yes, if there's not 'enough' content, you would see the lower div fill out the bottom part of your screen with the div 'lower' with it's bg image.

Comment: Here you can see how I did it with a table (shame, shame!) http://www.splendidmusic.nl/ But I want to solve it tableless!

Comment: Sounds like you want us to write your CSS/HTML for you?

Comment: Nope, I already build the website: http://www.splendidmusic.nl/ Just want it without a table... you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** This answer does not solve the original problem, I misunderstood his question. What the author wants to achieve is probably impossible with CSS only, because we have a combination of sticky footer, a footer-head that is always visible (like taskbar) and dynamic height of both the main content and the footer.

I'm leaving the snippet for anyone that might look for a sticky footer.

**Fiddle:** [Dynamic Content with Sticky Footer](http://jsfiddle.net/simple/cWLpm/)

I used a timer to illustrate filling the 'Upper' Container with content constantly.

**Basically you have the following HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="upper">
        <span></span>
    <div class="push">
    </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="lower">
        Footer content goes there.
    </div>
</div>​
```

**And of course, CSS:**

```
.upper{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* The negative value of the footer height. */
    color: white;
}
.lower, .push {
    height: 100px; /* Footer and Push need to have equal height */
    background: red;
    color: white;
}​
```

**Code explanation:**

This is basically the so called Sticky Footer concept on which you can do additional research. You have your main content, you have your footer and we use a little trick with the **push container** to literally push the footer so it doesn't overlap any of your content.

The extra CSS is just for the sake of the Demo, I hope you can clean it up and implement it the way you need it.

Comment: The footer (lower) should grow too. It should fill out the remaining part of the lower screen. Your solution has a fixed footer heigt...

Comment: I have came to the conclusion that what you want to achieve is improbable to be done with pure CSS. I am not sure, but I hope you find an answer. I'll just leave the snippet here as part of the discussion.

You already have a jQuery solution I've read, that should do well.

Comment: Yep, script it will be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not *precisely* what you are asking for, but you could scrap the bottom div, and add the large background image to `body`. Apply `background-position: center bottom;` to make the image hug the bottom of the screen. This will work particularly well if the image has a clear background.

```
body {
    background: url('largeImage.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Comment: Did you see my link http://www.splendidmusic.nl/ ? This is what I would like to do, but than tableless....

Comment: What would prevent the top div from overlapping the background image?

Comment: @madb, that's the "not _precisely_ what you are asking for" part.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ummm just set the height of div 'lower'? Or even min-height if you want it to be content flexible.

Comment: No, because then, in the case of the image in the question, there will be a scrollbar.

Comment: @JakeParis op said nothing about scrollbars

Comment: Check the comments under the question

Comment: Beside, if it were a matter of just giving the bottom `div` a specific height, I don't think this question would be here.

Comment: Well it's hard to think of what he wants to achieve

Comment: See http://www.splendidmusic.nl, this is what I have, but this is with a table. I want it tableless.

Comment: Search for fixed footer then, there are lot of comprehent topics around here covering this.

Comment: It's not a fixed footer, it's a screenfilling footer with a bg image

Comment: Body has this bg http://www.splendidmusic.nl/templates/splendid_tpl/images/hugewood_sides.jpg and footer has this bg http://www.splendidmusic.nl/templates/splendid_tpl/images/bg-footer.png footer overrides body bg, and it's always on the bottom giving the effect of covering while body bg goes down is this what you need?

Comment: Yes, but when I can use divs I might work out a better layout, with smaller images... But so far, no one has found a solution. (without script & tables)

Comment: What do you mean by screenfilling foooter? It's just BODY background that goes under the footer

Comment: the bg image should move downwards with the growing of the upper div... see the circle in my example. It should move up and down based on the content above it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to subtract the height of the `upper` div from the browser's window height, and if the result is larger than 0, set the `lower` div at that height?

For getting the window size, I suggest using this function. I believe it's cross-platform, though I haven't tested it recently.

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a jQuery solution myself too. But I am looking for a CSS solution. It sounds easy, but it's kind of harder then you think :-)

Comment: I take it it is a problem if the "lower" div causes a scrollbar to appear, in the cases in which "upper" itself isn't high enough to do that? If that is not a real problem, I have a pure-css solution for you.

Comment: Yes, 'it is a problem' :-) Maybe you MUST use script to get this done. (without a table) Thanks for your reply

Comment: I would almost say it is. I spent a very long time looking for a solution for a similar problem a while back, and eventually I just caved in and used Javascript.
You're very much welcome. Good luck!